# setting up multiple internal ip's windows server 2008 with IIS 7

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, iis-7

i've a Windows 2008 R2 server with 2 internal ip's and one external ip.
MyDomain.com is binded to the external ip.

Now i want to create 2 web sites in the IIS Manager.

First Website should work with this internal ip: 192.168.245.101
and the second with 192.168.245.102.

in the website binding settings i can chose rather 192.168.245.101 or 192.168.245.102

but only 192.168.245.102 is working.. if i bind a website to 192.168.245.101 it dont work.
How can i make this working? The port 80 is opened for both.

and my second question.. if i get those ip thingy work, how can i tell my domain to redirect to with mydomain.com to 192.168.245.101 and forum.mydomain.com to 192.168.245.102 ?

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a vital step.  You have no IP translation.  You need some form of PAT ([port address translation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation#Advantages_of_PAT)) in order to map multiple internal IPs to one external IP.

A better alternative would be to use host headers.  The only reason you need multiple IPs is for SSL websites. (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753195(WS.10).aspx)